# Can you weight certain datapoints less than others when training a model?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, neural-network, classification

Say, for example, I'm trying to make a classifier to classify a sentence as good or bad. I have a data set of 50% `good` and 50% `bad`. I would prefer to have a false positive and wrongly classify them as good than than wrongly classify them as bad.

Is there any way to achieve this and make sure that updates to parameters are not as significant when it wrongly classifies a bad sentence compared to a good sentence?

One solution I thought of is using the normal classifier without any modification and then just change the threshold to say that we will predict it is good if the probability of it being good is higher than 40% rather than the normal 50%. I'm not sure if this has any sort of side effects and if it would be better to directly modify it in the training process.

Answer (score 0):

Use weighted cross entropy.
In binary cross entropy [-(p)log(q) -(1-p)log(1-q)],
-(p)log(q) term is for judging true data true (1 to 1)
and -(1-p)log(1-q) term is for judging false data false. (0 to 0)
So, if you want to have false positive rather than false negative,
you can weight heavily -(p)log(q) term.

See tensorflow document.
(https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/weighted_cross_entropy_with_logits)